# Interactive Sorting on a Drill Down action collapses drill down

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, drilldown

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I have come across an issue with a drill down action and interactive sorting.  I am trying to sort a column, "Fill Date", that is found within a hidden Drill Down action.  I can expand the drill down by using the toggle but when I click the sort button for that column the table collapses.  When I open it back up, the data does indeed get sorted but what I want is not to have it collapse.  I know that the report is re-rendering but I was wondering if anyone knew of a workaround?

Comment: I don't believe there is a workaround unless you can change the underlying code that handles that. Since it is re-rendering like you said this is the only way to do it. Post it as an enhancement to Microsoft for future version and they hopefully will add it.

Comment: so weird, thanks so much for getting back with me

Comment: Sorry I couldn't have been more help.